# Analyzer reports that the following code leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, analyzer

Analyzer reports that the following code has a potential memory leak. Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm releasing the annotation that's been allocated.

```
  -(AddressAnnotation *)addAdress:(NSString*)placeTitle SubTitle:(NSString*)placeSubTitle Coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord withId:(NSInteger) placeId{
        AddressAnnotation *annotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
        annotation.placeTitle = placeTitle;
        annotation.placeSubTitle = placeSubTitle;
        annotation.museumId = placeId;
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation]; 
        return annotation;

        [annotation release];
    }
```

Comment: Change it to autorelease in the line where you alloc it, instead.

Comment: wait a minute, it is possible put something after the return statement in Objective-C ?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj: no, it's not. That's why hunumanDev's code is leaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
return annotation;
[annotation release];
```

to

```
return [annotation autorelease];
```

Answer (score 7):

You are releasing after the return, so never gets called.
Also note that the map view retains the annotation when you add it.